# Rows between two dates?

Tags: oracle

This may seem like a dumb question, but I rarely use SQL.

I have table `Empl_Transactions` with a datetime column called DATETIME_INS. This column has values that look like this `11/28/2016 2:23:00`.

I would like to return all rows where column DATETIME_INS has yesterday's date. So I've tried the following queries, but they don't quite return what I'm looking for. The first two queries that I thought would work return rows with today's date.

```
-- This returns rows inserted today
select * from Empl_Transactions WHERE 
DATETIME_INS >= SYSDATE-1 and DATETIME_INS < SYSDATE 

-- This also returns rows inserted today
select * from Empl_Transactions WHERE 
DATETIME_INS >= CURRENT_DATE-1 and DATETIME_INS < CURRENT_DATE

-- This returns 0 rows
select * from Empl_Transactions WHERE 
DATETIME_INS >= to_date(CURRENT_DATE-1,'DD-MM-YYYY')
and DATETIME_INS < to_date(CURRENT_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY')

-- works correctly, but I'm using a static value as date
select * from Empl_Transactions WHERE 
DATETIME_INS >= to_date('11/27/2016','MM-DD-YYYY')
DATETIME_INS < to_date('11/28/2016','MM-DD-YYYY')
order by DATETIME_INS asc

-- I get error "Not a valid month"
select * from Empl_Transactions WHERE 
DATETIME_INS >= to_date(CURRENT_DATE-1,'MM-DD-YYYY')
and DATETIME_INS < to_date(CURRENT_DATE,'MM-DD-YYYY')
```

Comment: Datetime datatypes contain the time portion as well, so if you just need the date portion, then use trunc function... as in: trunc(DATETIME_INS) = trunc(sysdate) - 1

Comment: The issue with using TRUNC is that it's taking over 2 minutes to display any results, where as using any of the filters that I've tried returns data almost immediately (even if incorrect).

Comment: btw there's no PL/SQL here.

Comment: @rbhatup The problem is not with TRUNC, it is in your fields passed to trunc! **TRUNC(SYSDATE)** {Time of OS} is no Equal with **TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE)** which is a value stored in your DB per record in table

Comment: I think you better create an index for your table on your DATETIME_INS field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
select * from Empl_Transactions WHERE 
DATETIME_INS >= trunc(sysdate)-1 and
DATETIME_INS < trunc(sysdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how you get yesterday's date:

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 1 FROM dual;
```

For your table, the query should be:

```
SELECT *
FROM   empl_transactions
WHERE  TRUNC(datetime_ins) = TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 1;
```

Comment: This works functionally but it would not be able to use an index on `datetime_ins`.

Comment: The issue with using `TRUNC` is that it's taking over 2 minutes to display any results, where as using any of the filters that I've tried returns data almost immediately (even if incorrect).

Comment: Basically, after two minutes the query hadn't returned anything if I use `TRUNC`.

Comment: In that case you can create and index for **datetime_ins** like this `CREATE INDEX idx_trunc_empltrans_dateins ON empl_transactions(TRUNC(datetime_ins))`